# Get better error detail on Azure deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

I am feverishly trying to track down all of the new errors that deploying a new app to Azure creates.  It would be greatly beneficial on Azure to get the same detail on the source error section of the error page that the local instance creates.

For example, on local I get:

[image]

But on Azure I only get:

[image]

So identifying which line is causing this issue is extremely difficult. Anyone know how to enable this?

**Edit:**

Below are the server 'Error Messages' configurations:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185074/how-to-get-error-details-on-azure-web-site ?

Comment: @JcFx no, that is in regards to customErrors not more robust error detail

Comment: I would think the Remote Desktop option still applies.

Comment: @Jcfx Yes, I have seen the child link and followed the steps, per that document, to no avail.  See my edit with the current configuration.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure then. I've done a lot of Azure debugging recently and have not noticed the error messages being any different from those via the local Azure emulator. Hopefully someone else will have an answer for you.

Comment: @JcFx Thanks.  Just for the sake of another data point, the behavior is the same on prod & staging.

Comment: Are you sure that your web.config transformation is not removing the debug attribute from your deployed azure code?  I think without the debug="true" attribute, you lose some of the in depth error detail

Comment: @Tommy Yes it did remove the debug="true" attribute from the config file.  Added it back on the server and restarted the app.  Still missing the detail.

Comment: One last thought, are you deploying the .pdb files with your application as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode

Comment: @Tommy I tried that and this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963604/deploy-pdbs-on-an-azure-web-role) and both did not work.

Comment: @Tommy also, yes the pdb's were being deployed

Answer (score 1):

The line numbers are part of the pdb files, so if you already have pdb files deployed, it may be that these were not built together...try rebuilding and deploying the pdb files...

Comment: Redeployed the app and associated pdbs with no luck

Comment: Are you precompiling your website before publishing to azure? This can cause the line numbers to be missing as well...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deploying your app as a website rather than a web role? I don't recall seeing any less detail in error messages from our Azure websites than I was seeing locally. Also, have you considered something like Elmah?

Comment: Appreciate the comment, but emlah is just showing what is already displayed in the stack trace. Not any of the detail I need in the source error section.